# Can I use winnt.h in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

My program is written in C. I want to use library `winnt.h`, but I don't use Windows anymore.

Comment: Why would you want Windows functionality on Linux ? That would be like going to an up-market restaurant and asking if you can order from McDonalds.

Answer (score 8):

Seems like a strange question; you should probably clarify which function(s) you actually need from winnt.h so that you can learn the Linux equivalent. winnt.h isn't really a general purpose "library", it's just an interface to built in Windows-specific functions.

With that as a major caveat, you may get some degree of what you want by attempting to run your app with the help of Wine. See http://www.winehq.org/ If you're just trying to run an existing app, that's may be a reasonable solution. If you're trying to make a Linux version of your app, though, that won't help you very much.

Answer (score 5):

No, well you could but it's not going to do any good - the.h file just declares functions that are defined in libs that are only on windows

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't.

`winnt.h` contains lots of macros that depend on a Windows environment and a lot of function declarations that only exist in Windows-specific libraries. So, it's not really useful (or possible) to use `winnt.h` on Linux.

*That said*, you *can* use [Winelib](http://www.winehq.org/site/winelib), which includes most of the functionality exposed by those Windows-specific headers, and you can get those features by linking your program with Winelib. In general, this is probably not a good idea, because Winelib is relatively unstable (the functionality of a given API function may be absent, incomplete, buggy, or incompatible compared to the native Windows version). It is a much better idea to look for a Linux-native alternative to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What parts of `winnt.h` do you want to use? Of course, if you need some nice macroses or type definitions from it, you can freely copy it to your own header file (of course, with dependencies). But if you include all `winnt.h` file to your program in linux environment, you will get tons of error messages. One of the reasons for it is pronounced by **Martin Beckett** in his reply.